# What is the best way to debug a python multiprocess script which fails to terminate?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am writing a python script which uses multiprocessing, multithreading and zeromq for interprocess communication. It all works fine until the program finishes: at that time the child processes terminate properly (sigwait is intercepted and the child procs terminate which I have confirmed with the ps command) but the main process often does not shut down - occasionally it does, but most of the time it does not.  I have confirmed that all remaining threads of the main process are daemonic and that the last row of the script is executed properly (it is a logging.info call). I am using fork for forking processes and can see that a Forkprocess still runs in addition to the main process.

What is the best way to debug this, considering that the script has actually finished ?  Maybe add a pdb or breakpoint() right at the end ?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the output, after the last row the script usually does not terminate:

`INFO root::remaining active child processes: [<ForkProcess name='SyncManager-1' pid=6362 parent=6361 started>]`

`INFO root::non-daemonic threads which are still running, preventing orderly shutdown: [].`

`INFO root::======== PID: 6361  main() end: shut down completed.=========`

**EDIT:**

I refactored the code and noticed that it now misbehaves very rarely. I am 99.9% certain that it is due to an open zeromq REQ/REP 'socket' at the time of shutdown. The refactoring made sure that these sockets are only held open only for a very short time - but it is not predictable what sockets are open at shutdown so occasionally it still hangs.

I will write a simple testharness with two processes communicating via REQ/REP sockets then shut down the child process followed by main process. I expect same result, i.e., interpreter not shutting down. Lets see, keep you posted.

Comment: I have added breakpoint() just before the last row and progressed with n(ext). Following calls are made after the last row, after the last call to atexit_call() it hangs:


> /usr/bin/python3.9.2/lib/python3.9/threading.py(1415)_shutdown()
-> atexit_call()
(Pdb) n

Comment: We need to see code to be able to answer.

Comment: Well, that's not so easy, quite a large application.  But I am confident that I have narrowed it down to zeromq REQ/REP socket state:  if the application shuts down while such a socket is open (and maybe if it becomes disconnected) then the process won't shut down.  I may be able to write a little test harness to confirm this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could try [viztracer](https://github.com/gaogaotiantian/viztracer). The good thing about viztracer is that it can display all the processes on the same timeline. Maybe you can catch what's stopping your main process/forked process from shutting down. If it's a deadlock it should be noticeable. However, without the code, I really can't tell if it would help for sure.